# How to searching odd number using python

Tags: python

I am trying using python to search odd numbers according to the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX4z4.png).

Code:

```
x = input()
i == 0
result == 0
if i < x:
    print(i = i + 1)
    print(result = result + 1)
else:
    print("odd number")
```

This is an image of the [Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP8wz.png) I am trying to integrate into this program.

Sorry if I'm bad at English because I am still learning thank you. :)

Comment: Please always put in the Problem statement, no image. So people can try it out and help you easily

Comment: `==` dose not assign a value to a variable.

Comment: You can also use mod (%). The remainder will always be 1 or 0. [More info](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/)

Comment: @Danielme the result of modulo can be greater than 1 too

Comment: Sorry, mod 2 will always return 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
result = 0
```

This will solve the problem initially.

`==` is used when if a comparison is used. Otherwise, to give/assign a value to a variable, `=` is used.

Comment: Also needed is `result = 0`